# How can a graphql variable be used in permission in Hasura?

Tags: graphql, hasura, graphql-mutation

I have a mutation. How can I create a permission in hasura using variables in the graphql query?

eg:

```
mutation MyMutation($name:String!) {
  insert_post(objects: {name:$name}){
    name
  }
}
```

How can I use `name` variable in the permission?

Answer (score 1):

Hasura v2 allows for this sort of pattern now.

For example, if you had a table that had a list of allowed names,
you could check that the name being inserted was in the list of
allowed names by doing something like this:

```yaml
insert_permissions:
  - role: user
    permission:
      check:
        _exists:
          _table:
            name: allowed_names
            schema: public
          _where:
            name:
              _ceq: ["$", "name"]
```

See also:

https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/3459#issuecomment-1085666541

https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/api-reference/syntax-defs/

Comment: actually I think this is not what the OP wants. He wants to use the actual GraphQL input value in the permission (`$name`), and not check for an existing value in the table.

Answer (score 0):

It's me on Discord.

Just for somebody has the same question. For currently, Hasura doesn't support to check permission from user input value, It only accepts value from `session variables` like `x-hasura-user-id`, etc.

But I think Hasura approach is correct when doesn't allow set permission base on user input.

If my answer is wrong, please correct, thanks.